# How to fix broken Debian?

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, software-installation, reinstall

These errors (see pic. 1 and 2) appear every time I boot in Debian. I tried to update from stretch to buster, but it didn't have any effect. I have dual boot with Windows 10, so that potentially might cause part of the problem.

It boots fine, however some things are broken (was able to run a program with clear stack smashing problem).

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Comment: Have you checked to see if there’s a firmware update for your system?

Comment: Please edit question and include the history about when the errors appeared, how long it work before (if it did), and what you did do. The errors are caused by non-confirming ACPI BIOS data. If you didn't upgrade anything (in particular the kernel), my guess is a hardware fault (e.g. bad RAM), these are no fun to track. If you upgraded, you can try fiddling with kernel ACPI options. A "stack smashing problem", whatever you mean by this, should be unrelated to to BIOS trouble, and is also a possible indicator for bad RAM.